# Applying fnFilter to a modified table

Tags: javascript, filtering, datatables

Using DataTables 1.9.4 and JQuery 1.4.4.
I'm trying to create a table which filters certain rows based on the visible column. The table is driven by an AngularJS like in-house controller.
When the table is displayed, the filter works fine, but thereafter, if the value changes, the filter is not updated.
The controller consists of an array (one for each row). When the table is updated through it, the filter is not reapplied. How can I make the filter reevaluate each row when the data changes?

HTML as generated by controller:

```
<table id="table-status">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>visible</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>name2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The DataTables initialization:

```
var oTable = $("#table-status").dataTable( {
"aoColumnDefs": [ { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                  { "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
                  { "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 2 ] } ],
    "bSort": false,
    "bFilter": true
} );
oTable.fnFilter("1", 0, false, false, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you need, but I rolled my own function to display or not some rows, based on a column called `Status`.

I have a checkbox that can contain the values `0, 1, 2` and `3`.

First, I get the regex function associating the values I want to filter:

```
var filter = "^" + $("#filterStatusCheck option:selected").map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get().join("|") + "$";
```

Which returns, for instance, `^1|2$`, meaning I want to filter the values 1 and 2.

Then, I `search()` the DataTable, looking for those elements (not me, actually, but rather their `search()` method.

```
var t = s.getTable().DataTable();
t.column(8).search(filter, true, false).draw();
```

Here, on column with the index of `8`, I'm doing so that it searches, using the above filter, and then `draw()` the DataTable again.

In your case, you might want to figure out what event you can attach the above code (maybe right after the row has been updated?). Your `filter` would be 1 (visible, right?), whereas your column search would be `0` (the first column called visible).

Hope it helps.